# Applying simple Touchswipe failure

Tags: javascript, touch, touch-event

I am just starting to learn applying some touch gestures and such and have decided to go with touchswipe. I am just starting out some testing and going from various things seen in the demos. However, I am not able to get a simple swipeLeft to work so far. Here is what I have thus far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../JQuery files/touchswipe.js"></script>

    <title>Demo</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    #swipe {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #99FFCC;
}

    </style>


  </head>
  <body>

        <div id="swipe">Swipe Here</div>

        <script type="text/javascript">var swipeOptions=
            {
                swipeLeft:swipeLeft,
                threshold:0
            }

            $(function()
            {           
                //Enable swiping...
                $("#test").swipe( swipeOptions );
            });

            //Swipe handlers.
            //The only arg passed is the original touch event object            
            function swipeLeft(event)
            {
                $("#test").text("wahoo");
            }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What specifically is not working? Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Also, it is not particularly safe to have spaces in your pathnames, like `JQuery files`

Comment: what is touchswipe.js, there are a bunch of libraries by the same name.

Comment: It isn't working at all yet. It isn't recognizing the swipe gesture.

Comment: Possibly I could somehow get a link to a simple tutorial to using Touchswipe? Other than the demo site itself.